# Attaching to docker container once built locally

Tags: docker

I copied dockerFile from https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/master/anaconda3/Dockerfile and executed built the container locally.

Tailing the last 3 lines of output during build:

```
Removing intermediate container 336f89d3f6d8
Step 9/13 : RUN echo 'export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH' > /etc/profile.d/conda.sh &&     wget --quiet https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh &&     /bin/bash ~/anaconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda &&     rm ~/anaconda.sh
 ---> Running in 3f431fcbc628
```

Apologies for newbie question "Running in" means container is built ?

So in order to attach to docker i use `docker exec -it 3f431fcbc628 /bin/bash` , can docker container be built while at same time attaching to container once built ?

Answer (score 1):

No need to apologise, that's how we learn ;)

So, a Docker image is made of layers. This means that every time you specify a command in your Dockerfile a layer gets created.

What you are seeing means that the RUN command is executed in the image layer 3f431fcbc628. You could check that (like you've just done) by docker exec into that layer.

However, during the building of a Docker image you cannot attach to the container. Once it is completely built you could attach to it.

Comment: Once the image is completely built...you could use it to **run a container**, and then you could attach **to the container**.

Comment: @Sergiu thanks, so the output "---> Running in 3f431fcbc628" indicates the container is  still being built ? Reason I ask is that building of container appears to hang on this output before I kill it, is this 'hanging' expected ?

Comment: @blue-sky you're welcome :) I am not sure why that happens and isn't something that should happen. Have you tried to use a base image like ubuntu and run the commands manually to see what is happening?